# How to display Python script output on screen, similarly to Conky

Tags: home-screen, scripts, bash, python

I use [Conky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conky_%28software%29) as a desktop monitoring software. I also use it to monitor stock prices and portfolio net worth through a Python script.

Basically, I fetch the stock prices from Yahoo Finance using curl.

> $ curl -s 'http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=vwrl.as&f=l1'

Then I input that to a python script that returns a float.

> $ python /yada/yada/myunoriginalscript.py
>
> 42.0

Conky handles this quite easily and displays it on screen. I know that curl can be made available for Android and I've ran Python scripts in the past.

**Is there any widget/app/technique to display the output of said python script on screen** continuously and not only on the terminal, whenever I run it manually?

Comment: How so? I want to display some data on my android phone. Which SE site should I post this question then?

Comment: Still: recommendations like *Is there an app for X* are off-topic here (see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for details). For where your question might fit better, you might want to look into [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/371/16575). With the correct phrasing and details provided, you might try your luck at [SR](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185). The other half is a development issue, and also off-topic. There's nothing built-in for that.

Comment: Well, I was hoping no need for apps, looking for some built-in software feature to display whatever the script returns on the status bar next to the clock or similar... I guess I might look for it on Stack Overflow. I will keep the question open just in case has some insight to offer and remove it afterwards if there is none. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no built-in feature for that (after all, there's not even built-in Python support). That's why I recommended checking with [Software Recommendations](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) (make sure to read their guidelines before posting there). I know there are several apps for Python support; some might come with widget stuff (though I've never heard of them either).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I installed [SL4a](https://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/) and used one of the the GUI functions that appeared on the 'test.py' sample script to display the information. I like the terminal, but this way is quite nicer.

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly what Blighty does https://github.com/P403n1x87/blighty.

Here is the documentation https://p403n1x87.github.io/blighty/

Comment: What is your connection to this app? This post seems promotional. Are you the developer, company owner, other? Is there a conflict disclaimer needed here? Please see Help about promotional statements made here.

Comment: I am the developer